# Unity3D Instanciar objetos como pares (Memory Game) aplicando shuffle

Tags: c#, unity3d

Me encuentro haciendo un juego de memoria donde tenés que girar dos cartas iguales para sumar puntos, de lo contrario las cartas vuelven a darse la vuelta.

Tengo hecho que me instancie de forma aleatoria las cartas en forma de grilla.

En mi código tengo un solo prefab que me instancia y solo lo repite. A esos prefabs repetidos, le asigna una textura aleatoria, aplicándole a su vez el mismo nombre para así comparar si las dos cartas seleccionadas coinciden.

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero debo hacer que se instancien a pares. Digamos: si instanció una K negra, debo asegurarme que se instancie el par de esa K negra. Y a su vez, que en la próxima partida, no se repitan las imágenes que utilicé en esa partida específica, aplicando algún tipo de barajado.

¿Alguien se ha topado con algo así?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui basicamente el problema es que debemos de garantizar que las cartas en el grid, sean pares todas. Podemos usar la siguiente estrategia para colocarlas en el tablero

Siendo `universoCartas` una coleccion **temporal** con todas las cartas de nuestra baraja

```
for(int i =0; i < numCartasUnicas ; i++){ 
    //tomamos aleatoriamente una carta del universo
    carta = universoCartas.get(unRandom(universoCartas.length));
    universoCartas.remove(carta);
    //cartas al tablero
    seleccionCartas.add(carta); 
    seleccionCartas.add(carta.clone()); // y su pareja
}
```

Ahora que ya tenemos todas las cartas que iran en el tablero, usaremos el mismo truco del random para seleccionar que poner en el tablero

Actualmente deberiamos tener algo asi:

```
{ G G B B E E C C A A H H } //identificando a cada carta con una letra
```

Ahora supongo que tienes un doble ciclo para poner las cartas en forma de grid

```
for(int i =0; i < n; i++ ){
    for(int j=0 ; k < m; j++ ){
        carta = seleccionCartas.get(unRandom(seleccionCartas.length));
        seleccionCartas.remove(carta);
        ponerCarta(i,j , carta ) //donde  i y j son coordenas en el grid
    }
}
```

**Nota:** el numero de cartas selecionadas debe ser igual a `n * m` (tamaño del grid)

Al remover de las colecciones, aseguramos no repetir cartas en nustro tablero